# Cannot Import Class in Python

Tags: python, module

I have the following project skeleton.

```
ex47 
    bin/
    docs/
    ex47/
        __init__.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        game_tests.py
    game.py
    setup.py
```

Working on Aptana Studio. In game_tests.py I have

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex47.game import Room
```

but Aptana is yelling at me for not being able to find Room, which I defined in 'game.py' as a 
class. When I run `nosetests` on command line I got Error: Import Error( no module named game).
What's seems to be wrong?

Comment: What python traceback do you get when you run it?

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in the top level ex47 dir?

Comment: Not really exactly relevant but you might try PyCharm IDE. There is a free and open source version and in my opinion much easier to use than Aptana because it automaticly handles a lot of issues like this for you. So especially you are not the most seasoned python guru you can at least get started on some really complex projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two issues:

- topmost ex47 is not a valid package (there is no `__init__.py`)
- topmost ex47 is not on your `PYTHONPATH`

The first one is obvious. If you want game.py to be importable using `ex47.game` then `ex47` has to be a valid package. So most probably you wanted to put it in the inner `ex47` which is a valid package?

When it comes to the second issue, python will look for `ex47` on your `PYTHONPATH` and in the current directory (the one you are in when issuing commands). Probably none of those is the case, hence `ex47` can't be found.

Considering the above, if you had the following directory structure:

```
ex47 
    bin/
    docs/
    ex47/
        __init__.py
        game.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        game_tests.py
    setup.py
```

and tried to run tests like this:

```
nosetests tests
```

while being in the topmost `ex47` directory it should work (note that there is no `__init__.py` inside the topmost `ex47`).

Comment: How do I set ex47 to my PYTHONPATH?

Comment: For the duration of current session `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/ex47:$PYTHONPATH`. If you want it in Aptana, then you should look into project properties, there are settings which allow you to modify the PYTHONPATH.

Comment: All right. I added /ex47 to PYTHONPATH just like how the manual did and I added __init__.py to top ex47 file. But Aptana still cannot read `Room`. What else can I do?

Comment: You don't need `__init__.py` in the top-level ex47. But in order to fix the issue, please try running `nosetests` from the terminal/console/shell in the way described. If that works, you will be sure that if inner `ex47` is on `PYTHONPATH` everything's fine. Given that, we can figure out why Aptana doesn't get it.

Comment: From /ex47, I ran that and got Ran 1 test in 0.003sec and Error: Import Error (no module named game).

Comment: Are you sure you have deleted the `__init__.py` from the outer `ex47` also the `__init__.pyc` if it existed ?

Comment: I deleted that and ran it again. I got `Ran 3 tests in 0.004s` and `ERROR: tests.game_tests.test_room_paths` .

Comment: This is not related to the original issue anymore. This means you have something wrong with your tests, but the `Room` class was imported just fine and the test ran. So I believe the original problem is solved :)